# Is it better to cite a PhD thesis or an article under review?

Tags: citations

A collaborator of mine has finished and defended his phd thesis, he has also submitted one chapter of the thesis as an article, and now this article is under review.

I am submitting an article and I want to cite this work, which one of the two should I cite? And if I cite the article should I use "Smith et. al, in review unpublished or pers. communication"

I was thinking that even though not peer-reviewed, a thesis might be better than something under review.

Comment: Might get different opinions on this, but I would say that if the thesis is publicly accessible, I would prefer to cite the thesis, but hopefully his article finishes review before yours does and you can replace with the new citation before final publication.

Comment: I would cite both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know if his article will be accepted? Would you know so soon enough? If there is a chance that it will be rejected (there always is but you may have a feeling of the quality of his article) I'd cite his thesis.

In any other case I'd cite his peer-reviewed article with *Smith et al., under review* or *Smith et al., submitted to (name of journal)*. Papers are usually more accessible and perceived to be of higher quality than theses and it would also give him one citation on his article already.

Or, as [Pont](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/32532/pont) pointed out, cite both: *Statement in your paper* (Smith 2016 [this would be the thesis], Smith et al., under review [this would be the pending article]).

Comment: There is no way to know if an article will be accepted ahead of time.

Comment: @user4050: Of course not but you may have an opinion of the present article or the past quality of works from your colleague.